# John and his condition

Tags: lateral-thinking

John is a nice looking guy, but he prefers to stay at home most of the time. John has a very warm relationship with Mary. Actually, Mary is the only person who is able to drag John outside once in a while. Nobody even visits John in his house, well, except for Mary, and also a cleaning lady once a week. But the cleaning lady tries to be really careful around John’s house so as not to touch anything. Because once she was not careful, and John nearly died. Needless to say that Mary was furious.

What’s wrong with John?

Comment: John has been having a lot of trouble lately ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2nd Answer** (totally unrelated to the first)
Is John

> A LEGO man or a doll of some sort?

John is a nice looking guy, but he prefers to stay at home most of the time.

> Since John is a LEGO man or doll, he is made to look handsome (objectively). But since he is technically not alive, he can't move outside his home.

John has a very warm relationship with Mary. Actually, Mary is the only person who is able to drag John outside once in a while.

> Mary is John's owner, and she like to play with him. If she has friends over, she'll even take him outside and play with him with her friends.

Nobody even visits John in his house, well, except for Mary, and also a cleaning lady once a week.

> Since John lives in a LEGO house, only Mary ever sees him there. Also, her cleaning lady (which may be her maid, sister, or mother), who picks up after her will put John back in his house if she leaves him out.

But the cleaning lady tries to be really careful around John’s house so as not to touch anything.

> Since John lives in a LEGO house, the cleaning lady must be very careful not to break it.

Because once she was not careful, and John nearly died. Needless to say that Mary was furious.

> Because John's house is on the floor of Mary's room, the cleaning lady stepped on his house, crushing poor John. I can only assume John's legs or head barely held together to the rest of his body as he screamed out in LEGO terror. Mary was understandably upset (as would any child), for her caretaker to step on her beloved creation.

Answer (score 3):

Is John...

> Blockquote ...a carved wooden man inside a cuckoo clock? He is "dragged out" of his "house" when Mary pulls the weights to keep the clock wound. The cleaning lady was careless and nearly knocked the clock off the wall, which would have broken it/killed John.

Comment: Not quite, but I even like this better than the actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is John

> A pet that's fairly sensitive and generally caged (e.g. a fish, a reptile, or a bird)?

Explanation

> People generally have good (maybe described as "very warm") relationships with their pets. Mary takes care of John by cleaning his house himself. The cleaning lady has to be very careful when cleaning the fishbowl / terrarium / birdcage, and not use any sort of cleaning fluid which could be toxic to animals. Or perhaps the lady nearly broke the container, which would be pretty problematic as well. Granted, a fish would be unlikely to be dragged outside (although when cleaning the fish tank water fish are generally taken out to a separate tank while the first is being cleaned, so I guess that could count too).

Comment: Nice answer! But incorrect, and also doesn‘t quite click.

Answer (score 1):

Does John suffer from

> [Severe combined immunodeficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severe_combined_immunodeficiency), forcing him to be a bubble boy?

He prefers to stay at home most of the time

> Because of his weakened immune system, John can't go outside very often or risk infection.

Actually, Mary is the only person who is able to drag John outside once in a while.

> Mary places John in a bubble ball, allowing him to walk outside without risk of infection.

Nobody even visits John in his house, well, except for Mary, and also a cleaning lady once a week

> Due to his condition, exposure to people for John is very dangerous.

But the cleaning lady tries to be really careful around John’s house so as not to touch anything. Because once she was not careful, and John nearly died.

> The cleaning lady must have accidentally broken his bubble, destroying his protection from the outside world. As a result, he got very sick and very nearly died.

Comment: That‘s a fitting explanation! But the truth is not so morbid.